# java extending a arraylist i would like to know what this particular piece of code does

Tags: java

i would like to know what this particular piece of code does

```
public class Sum extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    int sum;

    public int sum() { return sum;}

    public boolean add(Integer i) { 
        if (super.add(i)) { 
            sum += i;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is making a subclass or ArrayList that keeps a sum of all the members, which must be integers.

So, if used :

```
Sum s = new Sum();
s.add(55);
s.add(11);

System.out.println(s.sum());  // Will output 66, that is 55 + 11
System.out.println(s.get(0));  // Will output 55, the first element, ad every list
```

Moreover, it would be better to define it as

```
public class Sum extends ArrayList<Integer>
```

Otherwise the add method doesn't override the add(Object) inherited from ArrayList.

Comment: This is correct. I'll also add that the if-clause is not required here as super.add() will always return true for ArrayLists.

Comment: Also, a better implementation would also override other methods like `addAll()` otherwise the value of `sum` would be inaccurate if the final user decides to use this method to add more integers